# Do these two definitions of ring of regular functions coincide?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

I'm following Gathmann's notes (from 2021) and I got to the section on regular functions (on affine varieties). He gives the following definition, which I believe is pretty standard:

> **Definition 1.** Let $X$ be an affine variety (not necessarily irreducible), and let $U$ be an open subset of $X$. A *regular function* on $U$ is a map $\varphi\colon U \to K$ with the following property: for every $a\in U$ there are polynomial functions $f,g\in k[X]$ with $f(x)\neq 0$ and $\varphi(x) = \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$ for all $x$ in an open subset $U_a$ with $a\in U_a\subseteq U$. The set of all regular function on $U$ will be denoted $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$.

However, I don't find this definition very intuitive, specially when compared to other texts. For instance, an older version of the notes (from 2002), or Mukai's book, give an alternative one, which I think is more natural:

> **Definition 2.** Let $X$ be an irreducible affine variety. As its coordinate ring is an integral domain, it has a well defined field of fractions, called the set of *rational functions on $X$*, which we denote as $k(X) := \mathrm{Quot}(k[X])$. Given a point $P\in X$, the set of *rational functions on $X$ defined at $P$* is $$\mathcal{O}_{X,P} := \left\{\frac{f}{g}\in k(X)\colon g(P) \neq 0 \right\}.$$ Given an open set $U\subseteq X$, the set of *rational functions of $X$ defined on $U$* is the set $$\mathcal{O}_X(U) := \bigcap_{P\in U} \mathcal{O}_{X,P}$$.

I'm aware these sets are usually called the local ring of $X$ at $P$, and the ring of regular functions of $X$ on $U$, respectively. My first question is the following:

> Q1. Do these two definitions actually coincide?

This question is prompted because the texts tend to emphasize the fact that the local representations of a regular function may vary from point to point, ie. there is not a global representation of a regular function on all of $U$, necessarily. The thing is I'm failing to catch the local aspect of the second definition:

> Q2. How is the second definition local?

In particular, I'm struggling to understand the meaning of this example:

> **Example.** Let $X:= \mathbb{V}(x_1x_4-x_2x_3)\subseteq \mathbb{A}^4_k$, the open subset $U:= X - \mathbb{V}(x_2,x_4)\subseteq X$. The function
> $$
> (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \longmapsto \begin{cases}
>  \frac{x_1}{x_2} &\text{if $x_2\neq 0$},\\
> \frac{x_3}{x_4} &\text{if $x_4\neq 0$}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> is easily seen as regular on $U$ in the sense of the first definition, and has no representation as a quotient that works in all of $U$, which is fine by the definition.

The thing is, I can't wrap my head around using the second definition to study this example. I don't think the function is regular according to that definition. I don't even think is in $k(X)$.

> Q3. What is going on? Is the function actually regular in the sense of the second definition? How is it an element of $k(X)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main difference between the two is that you switched the role of $f$ and $g$. $x_1/x_2$ is certainly an element of $k(X)$, and it is also equal to $x_3/x_4$.